# Split pages in SSRS with parameters and different datasets

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dataset

I would like to know how to organize my report to be able to display few charts coming from different datasets depending on a specific field for the page.

So I would like to have 5 pages containing each 3 charts from different datasets based on the same parameter.

It is something like the wizzard generates but I am not able to add  a chart coming from other datasets and if I create another area with the parameter as header, it is splitted in 5*3 pages.

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting 5 Rectangle items into your report and add a page break after each one. You can then insert Charts into the Rectangle items, making sure they are sized appropriately. Also make sure the SSRS parameter points to the parameter used in the charts' Datasets.